# mvc c# upload image after resize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have an action which processes the uploading of a file. What I do is I check if the file size is 100kb, if not I resize it to a certain width and height (altho im not sure that's the right way to go to the desired size, thoughts?)

And then I'm planning to save it to a subdomain of my website.

this is how the action looks like

```
public ActionResult New(string account, int id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "File not found.");
                return View();
            }

            if (!ImageUpload.FileTypeValid(file.ContentType))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "File type is invalid. Please choose a different file.");
                return View();
            }

            if (file.ContentLength > 100)
            {
                Image image = ImageUpload.ResizeFile(file, 100, 100);
            }

            try
            {

                icdb.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sucesfully saved Image.");
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "OfAController", new { account = account, id= id});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

this is the resize method

```
static public Image ResizeFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, int targeWidth, int targetHeight)
        {
            Image originalImage = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true);
            var newImage = new MemoryStream();
            Rectangle origRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);
            // if targets are null, require scale. for specified sized images eg. Event Image, or Profile photos.
            int newWidth = targeWidth;
            int newHeight = targetHeight;
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            try
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), origRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    bitmap.Save(newImage, originalImage.RawFormat);
                }
                return (Image)bitmap;
            }
            catch
            {   // error before IDisposable ownership transfer
                if (bitmap != null)
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                throw new Exception("Error resizing file.");
            }
        }
```

so my problem is, im trying to find ways on how to save this resized file to my directory. And then I keep finding that I have to upload the image first before resizing? Is that right? Or is there a way where I can resize this before I save to my directory?

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You can resize it before saving, but you can't resize it before uploading to the server unless you do it in client-side script (like JavaScript).  Your C# will run on the server side only.

Comment: so i have to upload first, then retrieve then resize then save? is that how it's supposed to flow?

Comment: This is a good link to check out: http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2007/10/Resize-images-'on-the-fly'-while-uploading.aspx